# Defining priority queue

Tags: java, priority-queue

Consider the following declaration of the priority class `class PriorityQueue<E extends Comparable<E>> extends Queue<E> {` in contrast to the one provided in the Java packages, which 
 has a comparator as an attribute to compare. This instead forces the object for which the priority queue is maintained to have its comparable implementation. 
 Are there any pros and cons of this approach?

**My Thoughts:** 
One thing I can think of is that this will force the priority queue to use the object comparators and won't provide the ability to implement its custom comparator as the user 
 of the class may want to build the queue based on some different comparator.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Consider the following declaration of the priority class class PriorityQueue<E extends Comparable> extends Queue {}

What if you want to put an object in the queue, and this object does not implement the `Comparable` interface.

There is no need to restrict the placed object must implement the `Comparable` interface, which is more flexible.

For the same object, the logic of comparison may be inconsistent in different scenarios, so a `comparator` needs to be passed in from the outside, and the object itself does not need to implement a `comparator`.

(Above are my personal thoughts)